# How to set variable value from gtk_entry?

Tags: c, gtk

I would like to set var pid from entry, but I got the following warning:

> gtk.c:7:6: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default].

How I can make var pid == entry? It is very imporatant because this program is going to send signal to a process which id (pid) we are going to enter.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

pid_t pid;
void sendSighup(GtkWidget *widget,GtkWidget *entry, gpointer label) {

pid = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry));
kill(pid,SIGHUP);
}
void sendSigint(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer label) {


        kill(pid,SIGINT);
}
void sendSigkill(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer label) {

    kill(pid,SIGKILL);
}
void sendSigterm(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer label) {

    kill(pid,SIGTERM);
}
void sendSigstop(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer label) {

    kill(pid,SIGSTOP);
}

accept_clicked (GtkButton *button, GObject *context_object)
{
    GtkLabel *accept_lable1 = g_object_get_data (context_object, "label1");
    GtkEntry *accept_entry = g_object_get_data (context_object, "entry");

    const char *entry_in = gtk_entry_get_text (accept_entry);
    gtk_label_set_text (accept_lable1, entry_in);
}



int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
GtkWidget *window;
GtkWidget *frame;
GtkWidget *table;

GtkWidget *button1;
GtkWidget *button2;
GtkWidget *button3;
GtkWidget *button4;
GtkWidget *button5;
GtkWidget *quit;
GtkWidget *set;
GtkWidget *vseparator;
GtkWidget *entry;
GtkWidget *label;
GtkWidget *label1;
GtkWidget *label2;

gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Send Signal");
gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 300, 250);
gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);

frame = gtk_fixed_new();
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), frame);

button1 = gtk_button_new_with_label("Sighup");
gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(frame), button1, 8, 15);
gtk_widget_set_size_request(button1, 80, 35);

button2 = gtk_button_new_with_label("Sigint");
gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(frame), button2, 8, 60);
gtk_widget_set_size_request(button2, 80, 35);

button3 = gtk_button_new_with_label("Sigkill");
gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(frame), button3, 8, 105);
gtk_widget_set_size_request(button3, 80, 35);

button4 = gtk_button_new_with_label("Sigterm");
gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(frame), button4, 8, 150);
gtk_widget_set_size_request(button4, 80, 35);

button5 = gtk_button_new_with_label("Sigstop");
gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(frame), button5, 8, 195);
gtk_widget_set_size_request(button5, 80, 35);

set = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Set");
gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(frame), set, 200, 80);
gtk_widget_set_size_request(set, 80, 35);

quit = gtk_button_new_with_label("Quit");
gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(frame), quit, 200, 195);
gtk_widget_set_size_request(quit, 80, 35);

vseparator = gtk_vseparator_new();
gtk_widget_set_size_request(vseparator, 10, 240);
gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(frame), vseparator, 95, 5);

label = gtk_label_new("Enter PID:");
gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(frame), label, 165, 20);

label2 = gtk_label_new("PID:");
gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(frame), label2, 110, 89);

label1 = gtk_label_new("0000");
gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(frame), label1, 140, 89);

entry = gtk_entry_new();
gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(frame), entry, 120, 40);
gtk_widget_grab_focus(entry);

g_object_set_data(G_OBJECT(set), "label1", label1);
g_object_set_data(G_OBJECT(set), "entry", entry);

g_signal_connect(GTK_BUTTON (set), "clicked", 
            G_CALLBACK (accept_clicked), set);

g_signal_connect_swapped(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", 
        G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

g_signal_connect(button1, "clicked",
     G_CALLBACK(sendSighup), NULL);

g_signal_connect(button2, "clicked",
     G_CALLBACK(sendSigint), NULL);

g_signal_connect(button3, "clicked",
     G_CALLBACK(sendSigkill), NULL);

g_signal_connect(button4, "clicked",
     G_CALLBACK(sendSigterm), NULL);

g_signal_connect(button5, "clicked",
     G_CALLBACK(sendSigstop), NULL);


g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(quit), "clicked", 
        G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), G_OBJECT(window));


gtk_widget_show_all(window);
gtk_widget_show(entry);
gtk_widget_show(label);

gtk_main();

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that line you can either use the plain old `atoi`:

```
pid = atoi(gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry)));
```

or use a more complex function such as [`g-ascii-strtod`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-ascii-strtod).

Answer (score 0):

[gtk_entry_get_text](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.4/GtkEntry.html#gtk-entry-get-text) returns char* - a pointer to char. You are assigning a pointer to char to int in your code. This is implementation-defined according to C standard and is not probably what you want, this is why your compiler gives you a warning:

> 6.3.2.3 p.6:
>
> Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as
>   previously specified, the result is implementation-defined. If the
>   result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is
>   undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any
>   integer type.

For example, take a look at this code which is an exact representation of problem you have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
        char *p ="123456";
        int i = p;
        printf("%d\n", i);
        printf("%p\n", p);
        exit 0;
}
```

It prints:

```
134514096
0x80485b0
```

Pointer to char is assigned to int in line 7. This yields the same error as in your code:

> main.c:7:17: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer
>   without a cast [enabled by default]

Now let's see what's the result of this assignment - do not forget that this an implementation-defined behavior. First printf prints value of `i` variable after assignment. Second printf prints an address that a pointer holds using `%p` specifier which prints a pointer value in an implementation-defined manner. These values turned out to be the same - `0x80485b0` is hexadecimal `134514096`. What happened here is pointer value (that is an *address*) has been assigned to int. The same is happening in your code. C is a very simple language, it doesn't do anything behind your back. It will not automatically convert a series of digits written in a string to an int. To convert string to a number you need to use standard [atoi](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/atoi.html) function or a custom function provided by libraries you are using.